# Creating multi-series line chart in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, linechart

Hello I have the below data:

```
month_id            class   count
201612              B       69
201612              G       54
201612              P       31
201612              S       42
201612              V       89
201612              Other   77
201701              B       87
201701              G       79
201701              P       96
201701              S       68
201701              V       08
201701              Other   653
201702              B       67
201702              G       82
201702              P       60
201702              S       46
201702              V       96
201702              Other   72
201703              B       94
201703              G       62
201703              P       95
```

Now I want to show how the counts for each class vary across the month_id's through line chart.Something like below.

[image]

So the x-axis will have the month_id's and there will be 6 lines for each class and the y-axis will be for the count. My data is in df2.

I have tried doing the below:

```
# Create new column to make plotting easier
df2['class_date'] = df2['class'] + "-" + df2['month_id'].map(str)

# x and y axes
class_date = df2['class_date'].tolist()
count = df2['count'].tolist()

# Bokeh's mapping of column names and data lists
numlines=len(df2.class.unique())
mypalette=Spectral11[0:numlines]

plot = figure(plot_width= 800 , plot_height=350)
plot.multi_line(xs= [class_date]*numlines , ys=[count],
             line_color=mypalette,line_width= 3)
show(plot)
```

However this is giving me the below error:

```
Bokeh Error
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is not correct for `multi_line`. It expected a *list of lists* (or list of arrays, etc) where each sublist has the coordinates for each different line. By contrast, what you are doing makes one (flat) list:

```
In [1]: lst = [1,2,3]

In [2]: lst*3
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Your data needs too look like:

```
xs = [
    [ <list of x coords for line 1> ], 
    [ <list of x coords for line 2> ],
    ...
]
```

And similarly for `ys`. However, if you only have six lines to display, I might suggest just making six calls to `line`, instead of one call to `multi_line`.

Additionally, if you are using string (i.e. categorical) coordinates for your x-range, you need explicitly what pass the list of unique coordinates as the `x_range` parameter to `plot`. Categorical coordinates have no inherent order, you have to specify the order you want. See, e.g.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#categorical-axes